# What does the dot at the end of the permissions in the output of "ls -lah" mean?

Tags: ls, file-attributes, xattr

I found some Linux files, and when I type `ls -lah`, it outputs this permissions format:

```
... 
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root  
...
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root    root 
...
```

I would like to know, what is the meaning of the dot (`-rw-rw-r--.`) at the end of the permissions format?

Comment: ACL - see http://superuser.com/questions/230559/what-does-the-dot-mean-at-the-end-of-rw-r-r-how-do-you-set-it-with-chmod

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From `info coreutils 'ls invocation' | grep -1 '[.+]. character'` under Linux

```
GNU `ls' uses a `.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
     security context, but no other alternate access method.

A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
     marked with a `+' character.
```

Comment: But what if the dot is the first char instead of the last char in file permission?

Answer (score 15):

From GNU.org under [what information is listed](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html):

> GNU ls uses a ‘.’ character to indicate a file with a SELinux security context, but no other alternate access method.

This basically implies that the file has an [Access Control List (ACL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) with SELinux. You can set or delete ACL association for a file by using the [`setfacl`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html) command

Answer (score 13):

So *NOT* ACL, from @Tom van der Lee reference

> ```
> + (plus) suffix indicates an access control list that can control additional permissions.
> . (dot) suffix indicates an SELinux context is present. Details may be listed with the command ls -Z.
> @ suffix indicates extended file attributes are present.
> ```

An example on my machine:

```
$ ls -l 35mm DNS-cache 
-rw-r--r--. 1 graeme graeme     60 Feb 27  2010 35mm
-rw-r--r--  1 graeme everyone 5193 Jun  1 14:45 DNS-cache
$ 
$ getfacl -s 35mm DNS-cache 
$ ls -Z  35mm DNS-cache 
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 35mm
                                   ? DNS-cache
```

So the **getfacl -s** produced no output, because there was no ACL. There was however a security context (seen with **ls -Z**)

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Filesystem permissions wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Symbolic_notation), the dot indicates a SELinux context is present.