# tomcat not have write permission /usr/share/tomcat on RedHat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, openam, rhel7

When I try to install OpenAM 12.0.0 on Tomcat 7 in (RedHat)RHEL 7 I get an error that says `Configurator does not have write access to /usr/share/tomcat`. 
[image: OpenAM Configurator]
I installed tomcat 7 through `yum install tomcat` and when the process finish it created a user tomcat and assign right permissions to tomcat group

`ls -la /usr/share/tomcat`
[image: ls -la /usr/share/tomcat]
The tomcat is started with the user `tomcat` and I use to start this command `service tomcat start`.

The stranger thing is that the OpenAM setup can write inside of `webapps`, `logs`, `conf`, `temp`, `work` folders but can't write inside of `/usr/share/tomcat/`

I don't know if this is some problems with the way to RHEL 7 manage the permissions for tomcat or something like that.

Do you know any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution ^_^, the problem is related with the Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux, so I ran the next command and the problem was solved:

`semanage fcontext -a -t tomcat_var_lib_t "/usr/share/tomcat(/.*)?"`

`restorecon -rv /usr/share/tomcat`

thanks guys for your comments, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see the screen shot provided , my best guess will be that the group for /usr/share may be different than that of tomcat. 
You can either of the two things

> 1) change the ownership of the directory in question chown -R /path to directory tomcat.tomcat
>   2) start tomcat service as sudo service tomcat restart

If neither works can you provide the error the ls -l out put for the directory in question.

Answer (score 0):

That dot at the end of the permissions listing means you have an SELinux permission to contend with... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594871/the-meaning-of-a-dot).

You can try *temporarily* disabling SELinux and seeing if it works. Or checking your audit logs.

Answer (score -2):

Try this command on Tomcat file, then try once again.

```
chmod 755 /usr/share/tomcat
```

Comment: yes, I tried this `chmod -R 777 /usr/share/tomcat` but the result is the same