# Meaning of dot after file permission in directory listing?

Tags: android, linux, permissions, ls

I've decrypted and mounted an android adoptable storage. After I copied some files to the adoptable storage I notice a small difference between the file that were already on the adoptable storage and the ones I copied:

Already on the adoptable storage:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1023 1057  9146406 Jan  8 09:24 IMG_20220108_092445.jpg
```

and the one I copied:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 1023 1057  3554128 Jan  6  2020 IMG_20200106_182924.jpg
```

The difference is the dot after the file permission:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1023 1057  9146406 Jan  8 09:24 IMG_20220108_092445.jpg
          ^
```

I can't find any explanation in the man page.
The `stat` command mentioned nothing:

```
$ stat IMG_20220108_092445.jpg IMG_20200106_182924.jpg
  File: IMG_20220108_092445.jpg
  Size: 9146406     Blocks: 17872      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 12812558    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1023/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1057/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2022-01-08 09:24:46.932634035 +0100
Modify: 2022-01-08 09:24:46.942634035 +0100
Change: 2022-02-05 15:20:33.475347493 +0100
 Birth: -
  File: IMG_20200106_182924.jpg
  Size: 3554128     Blocks: 6944       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 12813144    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1023/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1057/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2021-09-23 18:45:24.169164252 +0200
Modify: 2020-01-06 18:29:26.982414836 +0100
Change: 2022-02-05 15:20:33.475347493 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Does anyone knows the meaning of this little dot after the file permission?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594871/what-does-the-dot-at-the-end-of-the-permissions-in-the-output-of-ls-lah-mean

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko Yes, that answer was quick!
To see the security conext call:
```
ls -laZ
```

Comment: Once upon a time I was struggling with those ACLs...